# Adding a highlight to the cell if empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code which works perfectly for what I need but I now want to add in color coding the cell where the input is missing. I am unsuree where/how to input the correct code of cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37.

```
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Select
    Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Columns(1).ClearContents
    Range("A1").Value = "Errors"
    RowCount = 0

    Set sh = Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template")
    For Each rw In sh.UsedRange.Rows

        FlagMissing rw, "B", "Payor ID"
        FlagMissing rw, "E", "TIN"
        FlagMissing rw, "F", "AccountNo"


    Next rw

End Sub

Sub FlagMissing(rw As Range, col As String, Flag As String)
    If Len(Trim(rw.Cells(1, col).Value)) = 0 Then
        With rw.Cells(1)
            .Value = .Value & IIf(.Value = "", "", ", ") & Flag
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

I would like to add a color into the cell where the input is missing.

Comment: It seems as if you left some important code out. The FlagMissing method is probably where it happens

Comment: If you are trying to do the entire row and not a cell it would be ```sh.rows(rw.row).interior.colorindex = 37```

Comment: If you can't edit the FlagMissing method, define which column you need to fill with color and use `sh.Cells(rw, column_index).Interior.ColorIndex = 37`

Comment: Sorry I forgot some code, I have added it now

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: also need to account for clearing the highlight if the user has fixed the problem...

```
Sub FlagMissing(rw As Range, col As String, Flag As String)
    Dim c As Range 
    Set c = rw.Cells(1, col)
    If Len(Trim(c.Value)) = 0 Then
        c.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 
        With rw.Cells(1)
            .Value = .Value & IIf(.Value = "", "", ", ") & Flag
        End With
    Else
        c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
End Sub
```